# Handle multiple port server

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming

I have to write a server which have to accept clients on ports that they have specified.
Example : `A` wants to connect on port 1337, so server listen on port 1337. `B` on 1992 so server listen on 1992, etc...

I don't know how to handle this.
Should I make a system like :
- All clients connects on the same port : XXXX ;
- The client's 1st packet specify the port he wants ;
- The server binds / listens / accepts on the new port ;
- The server answers the client that it's OK ;
- The client stops connecting on port XXXX and start connecting on the new port.
I don't know if this kind of system is good, but I can't figure out how else to do it.
Thank you, Florian

Comment: I think your solution would work.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. Why make a connection just to make another connection? Why not just have all clients connect to the same port? (And why is the client listening at all? Are you using UDP?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The question sounds like homework.

Comment: @kol: Usually this question comes from a misunderstanding about TCP and the idea that each connection to a server must have a unique port and therefore one side or the other has to assign a unique port for each new connection. Or some confusion that a server can't accept multiple connections to the same port and must somehow "move" them.

Comment: This is for a game project (shoot'em'up). The server has several rooms, each on a different port and with 4 players maximum. (I use UDP)

Comment: Having a different port for each room does not improve the situation. Rooms are a logic partition of clients while ports are at a different level, they are not related to the game and your game should not make assumptions on many ports being free to be open. Why can't you just store the association beween socket and room inside the code?

Comment: If you are using UDP then step 1, 3, 4, 5 simply don't exist since UDP doesn't have connections but just packets.

Comment: DavidSchwartz: Don't worry I understand how a connection works :)  
@Jack: I just wanted to know how to manage multiple ports !
Thank you all for your responses !!

Comment: Is each room a different port because a different process is handling it? If not, then why do it this way?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: yes each room is in a different process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want some kind of master process or central table that keeps the room to port mappings. You'll need clients to either connect to the master process or to some kind of "entry room" to get connected in the first place. Then, when they move from room to room, just look up the port they need to connect to, and refer them to the next port. All the central information can be kept in a database, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have at least one standard port open for clients to connect to if they're to communicate their requests about other ports. It doesn't have to be obviously open, it can just quietly accept UDP packets for instance, as some `ssh` hiding systems do. It can also work with TCP if you're willing to produce some kind of response that the new port is bound and ready.

In any case, listening on multiple ports is not especially tricky if you have the right framework. [libevent](http://libevent.org/) is an example of how you might get started.

It does seem odd that you'd have a standard port open as well as an unknown number of dynamic ports, though. When do you close these down? Do they time-out eventually? Is the listen call only short-term by nature?

Comment: "It doesn't have to be obviously open" : what does it mean ?

Comment: As in you don't need to respond with packets or appear to be open from a port-scanning perspective. You just need to be able to receive packets.